# “natural” sort an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting, natural-sort

I have an array which contains numbers and alphabets something like:

newArray = ["1 a", "1 b" ,"2 c", "2 a"]

I would like to sort them in a way that the output is expected as follows:

newArray = ["2 a", "2 c" ,"1 a", "1 b"]

What I want to do is sort the numbers in descending order and if the numbers are same, then sort alphabetically

Can I implement a comparison function in sort_by or is there a way to do that using ruby sort

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should use a better representation of your input. You can parse your existing array for example like this:

```
arr = newArray.map { |s| x,y = s.split; [x.to_i, y] }
# => [[1, "a"], [1, "b"], [2, "c"], [2, "a"]]
```

Then we can sort as we wish using `sort_by`:

```
arr.sort_by { |x,y| [-x, y] }
# => [[2, "a"], [2, "c"], [1, "a"], [1, "b"]]
```

Comment: I am new to ruby. So still learning. Is there a way I can convert the sorted map back to the original array format as I need to maintain the format for other comparison across the code.

Comment: @blathia: You can do that using another map and string formatting, for example with [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25). That said, I recomment not using strings to represent a tuple of values. You will lose type safety and handling of the strings will be awkward (as you can see, even for this simple application we need to parse the strings anyway)

Comment: Store `arr= arr.sort_by { |x,y| [-x, y] }` then do `arr.map{|a| a=a.join(" ")}`

Comment: @KirtiThorat: You realize I was intentionally not giving the complete solution? This has some didactical aspect as well :)

Comment: @NiklasB. I kinda thought of that but decided to make his life easy. :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @NiklasB. 's answer above (copied his `sort_by`)

```
arr.map(&:split).sort_by { |x,y| [-x.to_i, y] }

=> [["2", "a"], ["2", "c"], ["1", "a"], ["1", "b"]]
```

Comment: This is the more Ruby-ish solution.

Answer (score 0):

In a less elegant way, you can do that

```
    arr.sort! do |p1, p2|
      num1, str1 = p1.split(' ')
      num2, str2 = p2.split(' ')
      if (num1 != num2)
        p2 <=> p1
      else
        p1 <=> p2
      end
    end
    $stdout.puts arr
```